# Zoom to Layer Causes Points to Disapear

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, vector

[image]

I am trying to zoom in to individual points, but when I do they disappear and I am not sure why.

These points were shot in arbitrarily, I have not projected them onto anything as of now.

Comment: did you try this?: http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000006099

Comment: several solutions here: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/3756

Answer (score 1):

Delete and recalculate the spatial indexes. Right click shp or feature class in catalog, go to properties and it should be self explanatory from there